# jhipster: elasticsearch node not available

Tags: elasticsearch, jhipster

I'm using jhipster (version 4.14.3) to generate a web app. The problem is that in production mode, the app cannot connect to the elastic search service which is running well on port 9200. Any help would be appreciated.

application-prod.yml:

```
data:
    elasticsearch:
        cluster-name: elasticsearch
        cluster-nodes: localhost:9300
```

elasticsearch.yml:

```
cluster.name: elasticsearch
path.data: C:\Program Files\elasticsearch-6.2.4\data
path.logs: C:\Program Files\elasticsearch-6.2.4\logs
network.host: 0.0.0.0
http.port: 9200
transport.tcp.port: 9300
```

Exception details:

```
org.elasticsearch.client.transport.NoNodeAvailableException: None of the configured nodes are avail
able: [{#transport#-1}{localhost}{127.0.0.1:9300}]
        at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService.ensureNodesAreAvailable(T
ransportClientNodesService.java:326)
        at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService.execute(TransportClientNo
desService.java:223)
        at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.support.TransportProxyClient.execute(TransportProxyCl
ient.java:55)
        at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient.doExecute(TransportClient.java:295)
        at org.elasticsearch.client.support.AbstractClient.execute(AbstractClient.java:359)
        at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionRequestBuilder.execute(ActionRequestBuilder.java:86)
        at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionRequestBuilder.execute(ActionRequestBuilder.java:56)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's usually a version problem. Edit the **src/main/docker/elasticsearch.yml** in your jhipster project folder and install the same version of ElasticSearch server.